# Can historical high error rates cause Google Calendar APIs to timeout?

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

For the latest month or maybe longer, we've seen a large spike in read timeout errors such that we just can't seem to figure out. We've looked at DNS caching (ensuring that we aren't hitting stale A records), we've tried different HTTP transports (ex `ApacheHttpTransport` and `NetHttpTransport`), and we've played with timeout ranges of 5s, 20s (default), and 60s.

It doesn't seem to matter: any write operation (we make heavy use of `PATCH`) seems to have a ~30-40% chance of resulting in a timeout. This seems to happen for all our users (1000s, so it's not isolated to just some Google accounts). We utilize exponential backoff and 99.9% of the time our requests finally make it through, but the delays are frustrating for our users. We also utilize `If-Match` headers wherever possible.

I'm running out of ideas for what could be causing this. While we got the occasional timeout and 500 error when we first launched our product in January, we didn't observe anything close to this   level of failure.

One thought did occur to me: due to the nature of our product, we can make a large number of API calls that can cause various errors. For example, we often issue delete event requests not knowing if they have already been deleted, causing a "410 gone" response.

So... Is it possible that Google's APIs can "penalize" you if you make too many calls it doesn't like and, instead of rate limiting us or sending some other structured error, just decides to timeout the socket?

Comment: What do you mean by `timeout`? Are you receiving [this](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors#403_rate_limit_exceeded) error code? Besides this, have you checked your quota regarding the Calendar API? @PatrickLightbody

Comment: Yes I'm getting 403s, but that's not what this is about. We exponential backoff from those fine. 

What I was getting was dropped connections / read timeouts. The default Java client is 20s and even 60s would hit it. But after digging all day yesterday, I found that ~61s a real response comes back: 503 backendError (note: not 500 from that doc, which we _also_ get).

I also found the root cause! It had nothing to do with my usage pattern and everything to do with gzip compression on the incoming request. When I disable it, things become _way_ more reliable. I'll be filing a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause of my woes and it was a doozy. After trying different accounts and user-agent headers and anything that would rule out our specific requests being problematic, I then switched to a different client library entirely.

After much trial and error, I narrowed it down to the fact that the official Google Calendar API client library enables GZIP compression by default for outgoing requests. When I turn that off, suddenly everything was super smooth.

Exhibit A:

[image: metric chart showing 20s IO_ERRORs disappearing]

Obviously I think in general having gzip compression in both directions would be fantastic. But not if it causes the kinds of headaches I was seeing! We'll be filing a bug report with Google. My hunch is that the Content-Length header might be getting set slightly wrong in some cases, resulting in the request just hanging. Oddly, retries with the same payload worked fine, but I suppose there could be small variants each time (ex: timestamp, access token, etc).

Comment: I had the same issue and disabling GZIP compression saved my life!! Thanks Patrick Lightbody !!

Still sounds very strange that GZIP compression causes so exotic errors